# Double quotes in update query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have the following db in postgresql

```
create table car_wash(
  id integer PK,
  images text[]
)
```

To insert some data into images array I'm using spring boot, this is method from my repository interface

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value = "update car_wash set images=array_append(images,'' || :item || '') where id =:id",nativeQuery = true)
    void updateImage(@Param("item") String item,@Param("id")Integer id);
```

But when i put some string such as `F:\eclipse\workspace\TestMail\test.txt`in db this path is wrapped with double quotes `"F:\eclipse\workspace\TestMail\test.txt"`
I have no idea why, but when I'm trying to remove some strings from images aray using this query `UPDATE car_wash SET images= array_remove(images, '"F:\eclipse\workspace\TestMail\test.txt"');`it's not deleted.What is the reason?

Comment: The reason the delete doesn't work most likely is that the double quotes are not part of the string that's stored in the database. Why the string contains those double quote I can't tell, especially not without knowing where it comes from.

Comment: I'm just save file in remote server and do the following
private void addImageToCarWash(CarWash carWash, File newImage) {
        carWashRepository.updateImage(newImage.getAbsolutePath(), carWash.getId());
    }

Comment: Hmm, you might want to try `...' :item '...` instead. Since you're building the query in Java anyways there's no need for that string concatenation. Also try do debug your code to see where the double quotes are added to the string (`getAbsolutePath()` shouldn't do that).

Comment: Thomas , i found an answer, thank you for response

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found an answer . I don't know why but spring wrapp all the path strings into double quotes, to solve this you should to do th following `carWashRepository.updateImage(newImage.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"), carWash.getId());`